# VBA Macro To Search AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I currently have a code which searches an AutoFilter, but searches it for exactly what I put within the quotations.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="CLO "
```

What I need is a code which will search the filter for the word say "CLO " within each line. So say there's a line which says "CLO has been booked..." I want that to come up in the search. Currently, my search is returning no results since it is searching specifically for "CLO ".

Answer (score 3):

Update your code with the following

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).AutoFilter _
    Field:=5, Criteria1:="CLO *"
```

`*` indicates that as long as the text begins "CLO ", the row will be returned, regardless of text follows it.